# Firefox 9 and some phones are showing security warning on http site

Tags: wordpress, firefox, ssl

There is website http://blog.goworkabit.com built on wordpress which shows invalid SSL certificate warning when requesting http version of it. Site supports both http and https but https is meant for only admin and has invalid certificate. Public site should not request anything over https. Reproducable browser is Firefox 9 and some phones, most tested new browsers don't show the warning and all is good.

Screenshots are https://i.stack.imgur.com/rARpE.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLJZm.png

Firebug did not reveal anything to be loaded over https which could cause invalid certificate warning.

How to debug the issue and find what is causing invalid certificate warning on some older browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a link to:

https://blog.goworkabit.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/favicon.ico

Which is using a cert issued to **www**.goworkabit.com, so is not valid.